# After exception caught control going back to caller class

Tags: java, try-catch

Hi in my code there is one input file. Job of the code is to insert each record into a db2 table. There are 2 classes.

The main class reads each record and calls a method of another class to insert row into db2 table.

I found that while an insert fails with duplicate insert, control goes to caller class again and program tries to process the next record from file.

My understanding was, once exception is caught, the program will stop and won't  run for future processing. Can anybody please guide. Thanks

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class UpdateInsert {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        Update upd = null;

        try {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("H:\\exception.txt"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("H:\\file1.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String s = "";
        try {
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] vals = s.split(",");

                if (vals.length < 3) {
                    bw.write("Invalid record found - " + s);
                    continue;
                }

                if (vals[0].equals(" ") | vals[1].equals(" ")) {
                    bw.write("Invalid record found - " + s);

                } else {
                    upd = new Update();
                    upd.Setc1(vals[0]);
                    upd.Setc2(vals[1]);
                    upd.Setc3(vals[2]);
                    upd.MethodUpdate();

                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                bw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}



class Update {
    Statement stmt;
    Connection con;
    String c1 = "";
    String c2 = "";
    String c3 = "";

    void Setc1(String c1) {
        this.c1 = c1;
    }

    void Setc2(String c2) {
        this.c2 = c2;
    }

    void Setc3(String c3) {
        this.c3 = c3;
    }

    void MethodUpdate() {
        String subsys1 = "", creator1 = "", sql = "";
        subsys1 = "XXXX";
        creator1 = "XXXXXXX";

        sql = "'" + c1 + "'" + "," + c2 + "," + "'" + c3 + "'";

        try {
            Connection con = DBConn.getDBConnect();
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO " + subsys1 + "." + creator1
                    + ".MY_TABLE VALUES ( " + sql + ")" + ";");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }   }}
```

Comment: That is because you are catch the exception in the method. Check your code carefully. You will find a `catch` clause which is essentially handling this for you.

Comment: Share your code in your question, man/lady!

Comment: Might be worth a read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 0):

Once the exception is caught in a method, the program **wont** stop. The `catch` block executes and the control flows back to the calling method.

In your case, if the `catch` block in method `MethodUpdate()` executes then the control will be back to the next iteration of your `while` loop: `while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)`

In essence, if an exception is caught then `catch` block executes and thereafter all statements after the `catch` block execute and the control flows as usual. The program doesn't stop after `catch` block executes.

The only statements which won't be executed are the statements in the `try` block, after the statement which produces the exception.